# How to view workspace mappings using p4 client

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to automatically create a jenkins project, populating the Source Code Management mappings with a replica of my current perforce workspace mappings.
For instance, I want to transpose these settings into my jenkins builder:

```
//depot/...      //marco/mydepot/...
//utils/...      //marco/myutils/...
//projects/...   //marco/myprojects/...
```

I'm however unable to retrieve the current workspace view from the command line.
I'm aware that I have the **workspace** command:

```
C:\views> p4 workspace wks-marco
```

But this one opens a text editor with the current workspace configuration. But I need to actually capture this content. Redirecting to a file unfortunately did not work.

Any ideas on how to export the workspace mappings into a file or standard output?

Thank you advance for your time,
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `p4 help client` or `p4 help workspace` (`workspace` is a synonym for `client`):

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 help workspace

    client -- Create or edit a client workspace specification and its view
    workspace -- Synonym for 'client'

    ...
    p4 client -o [-t template] [-T type] [name]
    ...

        The -o flag writes the named client spec to the standard output.
        The user's editor is not invoked.
```

Running `p4 client -o` will output the client spec to stdout rather than writing it to a temp file and opening the editor.

In addition, if you have a depot of `Type: spec`, every specification (including client specs) is automatically saved to that depot as a text file, so you can also pull it out of there (e.g. `p4 print //spec/client/wks-marco`), including all of its old versions.  See `p4 help depot` for more on creating depots.

Comment: That works.  I also was not aware of the p4 help option. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You may need to add ".p4s" to the workspace name.

Comment: This is almost certainly (yet another) Perforce bug, but I've found that the workspace spec shown in //spec/client/... is always wrong.

It seems to be the _previous_ version of the workspace spec, not the current one.

As there's no associated changelist, this makes it effectively useless.

Comment: Contact `support@perforce.com` with repro steps — that’s certainly not how it’s supposed to work.